# How can I strech an axis of a plotly plot?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

See the image in the link for reference: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlxV5.png)

Even though the figure is pretty wide, the plot itself is way to small. Adjusting the figure size however doesn't improve the size of the plot.

Is there a way to strech the xaxis for example, to have a wider scatter plot over the whole screen?

Edit: This is the code I used:

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(data_scatter, x='x', y='y', z='z',
    color=data_scatter['Status'])
fig.show()
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlxV5.png)

Comment: Did you use `axis('equal')`?

Comment: Nope, I just added the code I used

Comment: Try this:`fig.update_layout(height=800, width=800)`

Comment: It is better now, but is there a way to change the ratio of the plot within the figure? For example that the ratio between x:y:z is 3:1:1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to play with the aspect ratio:

```
fig.update_layout({"scene": {"aspectratio": {"x": 2, "y": 2, "z": 0.75}}})
```

Here are a couple of pictures. The first without setting aspect ratio, the second with the code above:

[image]

[image]